# RHEL5 - Can't update packages because of i386 rpm conflicting with x86_64 rpm

Tags: yum, rhel5

When trying to run yum update, I receive the following errors:

```
Downloading Packages:
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Finished Transaction Test


Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/lib/rpm/macros from install of rpm-4.4.2.3-36.el5_11.x86_64 conflicts with file from package rpm-4.4.2.3-36.el5_11.i386
  file /usr/lib/rpm/noarch-linux/macros from install of rpm-4.4.2.3-36.el5_11.x86_64 conflicts with file from package rpm-4.4.2.3-36.el5_11.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man8/pam_sss.8.gz from install of sssd-client-1.5.1-71.el5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package sssd-client-1.5.1-70.el5.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man8/sssd_krb5_locator_plugin.8.gz from install of sssd-client-1.5.1-71.el5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package sssd-client-1.5.1-70.el5.i386

Error Summary
-------------
```

I've tried forcing the individual packages to be updated but I haven't had any luck. Can anyone help me resolve this? It looks like x86_64 packages and i386 packages are butting heads. This was run with the skip-broken flag set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is better if you use the whole packet name in this case

```
yum remove rpm-4.4.2.3-36.el5_11.i386
```

and

```
yum remove sssd-client-1.5.1-70.el5.i386
```

Comment: This ended up being closest to what I did. sssd-client uninstalled without a problem, but trying to remove rpm.i386 gave a bunch of child dependencies (mostly related to net-snmp) which all had to be uninstalled. After rpm was uninstalled, I ran the update and reinstalled the dependencies. Seems to be mostly stable at this point.

Answer (score 2):

remove conflicted packages:

> yum remove rpm sssd-client

and then install them back:

> yum install rpm sssd-client